# Override Nuxt.js auth module's strategies parameters

Tags: nuxt.js, laravel-passport

Is there a way to override **Nuxt.js** auth module's strategies configuration ? For instance, can I move the `redirect_uri` parameter from `nuxt.config.js` to a method in `pages/index.vue`.

Authentication configuration in `nuxt.config.js`:

```
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      'laravel.passport': {
        url: 'http://laravel.test',
        client_id: 2,
        client_secret: 'S0gpcgfIDgbvIHCL3jIhSICAiTsTUMOR0k5mdaCi',
        redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000'
      }
    }
  }
```

Login method in `pages/index.vue`:

```
async login () {
  await this.$auth.loginWith('laravel.passport', {
    data: {
      // All the 3 parameters below don't seem to be taken into account.
      username: 'me@home.com',
      password: '1qaz@WSX',
      // If 'redirect_uri' is removed from 'nuxt.config.js'
      // and moved below, logging in returns an error.
      redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000'
    }
  }).then((r) => {
    console.log(r)
  }).catch((e) => {
    console.log(e)
  })
}
```

Comment: are you use [Nuxt Auth](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/)

Comment: Yes I’m using Nuxt auth module

Comment: Have you already tried this? [https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/options.html#redirect](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/options.html#redirect )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 this.$auth
      .loginWith(<yourStrategy>, {
        params: { redirect_uri: <youURI> },
})
```